# Removing redundancy in an array of objects

Tags: objective-c

I have an array that contains objects of type `Song`, each object contains a string value named `title`.

I need to check if this array has objects with that has the same title, if yes, remove the redundancy of the objects with same title.

How can i do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your Song class's `isEqual:` method treats songs with the same title as equal:

```
NSArray *nonUniqueList = ...;
NSSet *uniqueSet = [NSSet setWithArray:nonUniqueList];
NSArray *uniqueList = [uniqueSet allObjects];
```

**Edit:** 
As per Alladinian's comment, if you need to preserve order of the original list, use `NSOrderedSet`.

Comment: Regarding the order part, it's really not that complicated. You can just use `NSOrderedSet` instead.

Comment: Good point.  I never use NSOrderedSet because it's really not as generic as NSSet.  For this particular problem, though, it would be perfect.